# Using required_unless for array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I do have 3 select ..

```
<select name="roles" id="roles" class="form-control" ng-model="newUserFormData.roles" multiple required>
    <option ng-repeat="role in roleList" value="<% role.id %>"><% role.name %></option>
</select>

<select name="sites" id="sites" class="form-control" ng-model="newUserFormData.sites" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="site in siteList" value="<% site.id %>"><% site.name %></option>
</select>

<select name="projects" id="projects" class="form-control" ng-model="newUserFormData.projects" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="project in projectList" value="<% project.id %>"><% project.name %></option>
</select>
```

> **Note:**
>
> 1. the Roles can be multiple .. is front-end required ..
>
>    - (1) - Admin (not included in the options)
>    - (2) - Lead
>    - (3) - Analyst
>    - (4) - Key Entry
> 2. the Sites can be multiple .. not front-end required ..
>
>    - (1) - Loc 1
>    - (2) - Loc 2
>    - (3) - Loc 3
> 3. the Projects can be multiple .. not front-end required ..
>
>    - (1) - Project 1
>    - (2) - Project 2
>    - (3) - Project 3

now my validator ..

```
protected function validatorName(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [ 
        'roles' =>  'required|array|min:1',
        'sites'  => 'required_unless:roles.*,in:2|required_unless:roles.*,in:3',
        'projects'  => 'required_unless:roles.*,in:2|required_unless:roles.*,in:3',
    ],[
        'sites.required_unless' => 'Site is required unless Lead or Analyst is selected as role.',
        'projects.required_unless' => 'Project is required unless Lead or Analyst is selected as role.',
    ]);
}
```

**Problem:**

- When I select either Lead/Analyst as the role, it is still requiring sites and projects when supposedly should not.

  > Request Payload:
  >   roles: ["3"],
- When I select Key Entry as the role, it is still requiring sites and projects even there are values.

  > Request Payload:
  >   projects: ["1"], roles: ["4"], sites: ["2"],

What am I missing ?

Comment: For one, you should only need one `required_unless` per input name. Try: `'required_unless:roles.*,in:2,3` and rename the select boxes `roles[] sites[] projectes[]`

Comment: Oh, in the documentation of `in:` says `The field under validation` must contain one of following values

Comment: thank you for ur comment .. will try that out on monday .. i just got out from work